# Getting SIGABRT when trying to compare some strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm doing some kind of search in my NSMutableArray, but I often get SIGABRT. I'm new to objective-c so I don't know if I missed something important here...

```
-(IBAction)findButtonPushed:(id)sender
{
    Data *stuff = [Data getInstance];
    [stuff.results removeAllObjects];
    NSMutableArray *tempResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (Company *company in stuff.companies) {
        if ([company.Description rangeOfString:[sbWhat text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
            || [company.Name rangeOfString:[sbWhat text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
            || [company.Url rangeOfString:[sbWhat text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
            || [company.FirstName rangeOfString:[sbWhat text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
            || [company.LastName rangeOfString:[sbWhat text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
            || [company.Keywords rangeOfString:[sbWhat text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
            [tempResults addObject:company];
        }
    }


    if (![[sbWhere text] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        for (Company *company in tempResults) {
            if ([company.Street rangeOfString:[sbWhere text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
                || [company.City rangeOfString:[sbWhere text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
                || [company.ZipCode rangeOfString:[sbWhere text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
                || [company.State rangeOfString:[sbWhere text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
                || [company.AddressPt1 rangeOfString:[sbWhere text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
                || [company.AddressPt2 rangeOfString:[sbWhere text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
                || [company.Country rangeOfString:[sbWhere text] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
                [stuff.results addObject:company];
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        stuff.results = tempResults;
    }


    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowResults" sender:self];
}
```

Btw, sbWhere and sbWhat are UISearchBars

I'm getting SIGABRT on these two if statements. Companies I get by parsing json string.

Comment: I love those conditional expressions

Comment: Holy God, that's a lot of logical ORs.

Comment: What's the entire error message printed to the console before the SIGABRT?  I'd bet dollars to donuts it's something like "Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xDEADBEEF".

Comment: You really need to post the actual exception that's causing the SIGABRT

Comment: Didn't even know that I have debug output in the console. I'm gonna look into it asap (I'm not with the computer at the moment) and let you know. Thanks for the info nontheless. Vote up.

Comment: OR what? sorry, had to. Guessing you didn't miss any conditions. Yes the exception should help.

Comment: Haha, no problem. It really does look messy. I'm pretty sure conditions are correct though. Exception comming soon.

Comment: There's nothing in the output :(. Here's the output...
...Attaching to process 2615.
Pending breakpoint 5 - ""ResultsTableViewController.m":28" resolved
Pending breakpoint 6 - ""ResultsTableViewController.m":19" resolved
Pending breakpoint 7 - ""ViewController.m":101" resolved
Pending breakpoint 8 - ""ViewController.m":154" resolved
Pending breakpoint 9 - ""ViewController.m":136" resolved
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: This happens every time if sbWhat and sbWhere are empty btw. So I thought maybe rangeOfString does not work if I'm searching through empty string, but it does, it returns NSNotFound.

Answer (score 3):

You do not check for `nil` text. If you pass `nil` to `rangeOfString:` it will throw an exception. Also you should store the string rather than call the same method multiple times.

```
NSString *what = [sbWhat text];
//Make sure what is not nil or empty
if([what length])
    for (Company *company in stuff.companies) {
        ...


NSString *where = [sbWhere text];
//Make sure where is not nil or empty
if ([where length]) {
    for (Company *company in tempResults) {
        ...
```

---

The console also likely regurgitated some text that you should include in your post from now on. E.g.:

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString
>   rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: nil argument'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x149c022 0x162dcd6 0x1444a48 0x14449b9 0x9360f6 0x96e17c 0x2a5f 0x2825 0x1) terminate called throwing an
>   exception`

Comment: I checked for nils before I posted here. JSON parser that I use puts empty strings in places where attributes are missing in the json string.

Gonna look into the output ASAP.